# Next refresh time info of each materialized views

Tags: oracle

I am able to find last refresh time from dba_mviews, but how or from where I will get the next refresh time info of each materialized views ?

Comment: Well in case of `REFRESH ... ON DEMAND` it can be anytime, even "never"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how it is refreshed:

1. set-up within the Snapshot:  there is a refresh interval
2. set-up with JOB or Scheduler: Check JOB or Scheduler Queues
3. set-up with Other mechanism: check with that mechanism